# RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device
```

However, both my tensor are using `.to(device=t.device)`.

```
            self.indices_buf = torch.LongTensor().to(device=t.device)
            self.beams_buf = torch.LongTensor().to(device=t.device)
            self.beams_buf_float = torch.FloatTensor().to(device=t.device)
```

Here `self.beams_buf_float.type(torch.LongTensor)` gives `Expected all tensors to be on the same device` error.

```
        torch.div(self.indices_buf, vocab_size, out=self.beams_buf_float)
        self.beams_buf = self.beams_buf_float.type(torch.LongTensor)
```

I am confused here, as all of them are using `device=t.device`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `self.beams_buf_float.type(torch.LongTensor)`, the resulting tensor  device is set to the default one (i.e. `cpu`).

The correct way to cast your tensor to a new type while maintaining the original device is by calling `self.brams_buf_float.to(torch.long)` or `self.brams_buf_float.long()`